# How to find old rows not in the top 10 and delete them using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a high scores table that stores a list of scores and dates.  I'd like to find all the scores not in the top 10 that are over a month old.  I have the following query which is partially what I want:

```
SELECT userId FROM highscores
  WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),
                 DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0
  ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10,18446744073709551615
```

What it does:

Find all the scores that were submitted at least a month ago and are not in the top 10 of **those old scores**.

What I'd like it to do:

Find all the scores that were submitted at least a month ago and are not in the top 10 of 
**all scores**

Is that simple?

**Edit:**  The version of MySQL I'm using doesn't support LIMIT it subqueries.  When I try it, I receive the following error:

> #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &
>   IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

**Edit 2:** I'd actually like to delete these scores from the table, I was just using a SELECT statement since I figured it would be simple to convert the select to a delete, but I'm not too familiar with subqueries and joining on the same table and deleting from there.

Comment: Does your host support temporary tables?  You could select the high scores into a new temp table.

Comment: @Ed see my edit below, which solves the LIMIT limitation :)

Comment: @Ed? Was the DELETE query helpful? Did it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>how about:</del>

```
SELECT userId FROM highscores
  WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),
                 DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0
  AND userId NOT IN (SELECT userId FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10)
```

**EDIT:**

You are correct. MySQL does not allow `LIMIT` in a subquery when using `IN (...)`.
Here is another solution which I just tested, and should work.

```
SELECT h.userId 
FROM highscores h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userId FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10) as t
    ON t.userId  = h.userId 
WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0
  AND t.userId IS NULL
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
DELETE h.* 
FROM highscores h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userId FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10) as t
    ON t.userId  = h.userId 
WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0
  AND t.userId IS NULL
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.  But I tried it and apparently whatever version of MySQL my host is using doesn't support LIMIT in subqueries.

Comment: That looks like it does the trick, and I thought it would be easy to convert that to a DELETE statement, so I didn't include it in the original question, but... how do I turn that into a delete statement?  Regardless, I'll accept your answer if nothing else comes up, since it did answer my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Split it up. First, make a query that gets you the top 10 entries:

```
SELECT id FROM entries ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

Then write a query that gives you everything older than a month:

```
SELECT * FROM entries  WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0
```

Now combine these into one:

```
SELECT * FROM entries  WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) < 0 AND NOT id IN (SELECT id FROM entries ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10)
```

That should do the trick.